# Warming up of the JSON serializer on a JAX-RS endpoint

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I am using JAX-RS whereby I have an interface which contains annotated methods for my endpoints (Apache CXF). I am using Jackson as my serializer.

I have noticed that the first request is particularly slow. This is because the JSON serializer is building its internal metadata on how to serialize/deserialize a given type on the first request.

It is possible to get Jackson to do this upfront (before the first request) by registering the type with Jackson. Is it possible to do this in a generic way, such that I have an interface and using reflection it goes and finds all the inputs and outputs to the JAX-RS annotated methods and registers the types with Jackson?

I figured this must be an "already solved" problem and in the vein of DRY - is there something out there that will do this already without me having to write some nasty reflection code myself? (Or any helper methods in Spring etc that could help here?)